# Can't redefine Error.prototype.toString in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to redefine method **toString** of *Error.prototype object*, I can't do it in Google Chrome Canary, but I can do it in Firefox.

You can try to do it by your own, here is the code:

```
Error.prototype.toString = () => 'booooka'
throw new Error('Message, that have never been shown') // "booooka" in Firefox, "Message" in Google Chrome
```

1. What is a problem doing this in Google Chrome?
2. How I can do this in Google Chrome?

Firefox: 57.0.4
Chrome: 66.0.3356.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit)

P.S. I have tried to paste this code to jsbin/jsfiddle, but I have the same result as in the Chrome. I am confused, maybe you can help me with that.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do this, by the way?

Comment: I need to change the Error.message without creating my own Error (with ES6 classes extend OR prototype method).
So, basically, I need to do something like that:

`functionThatNotDefined(); // ReferenceError: My Own message`

Comment: But why do you want to do *that*? For source mapping or something? Hiding sensitive information from an error message?

Comment: Sorry for long-time to answer, I had wanted to redefine global error messages to solve task on codewars, but it was wrong approach to do that.
If you interesting in this task, feel free to ask me about that (this task is really cool & interesting to solve)!
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think, that there is no way to redefine global error's default messages, because they are inside c++ files, and we can't access to them from javascript.

Comment: That’s not why. You can do it if you have an error object. There’s just no way to hook into preexisting constructors in JavaScript in general, regardless of whether they’re defined in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome lets you override `toString` just fine, but its console shows you the error’s `stack` instead of its `toString()`. Since the `stack` property is defined as an own property instead of being assigned to, there’s no neat way to override it (and possibly no way to override it period).

Consider this type of constructor:

```
const defineProperty = Object.defineProperty;

const Error = function () {
    defineProperty(this, 'stack', {
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: '…',
    });
};
```

I’m not aware of *any way at all* to change the value of `new Error().stack` in this context compared to what the constructor set.

That’s probably a good thing, though. What’s your goal?

Comment: Thank you, but it is not what I want.

Comment: @Avernikoz: What isn’t what you want? I didn’t provide a solution – I explained that there were no solutions. The snippet here illustrates how the `Error` constructor defines a `stack` property in a way that’s impossible to override.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer, if you do :

```
throw new Error('Message, that have never been shown').toString();
```

'bookah' will be shown, so the issue is related with the implementation of the Error class rather than with overriding prototype properties